# Is there an API that I can consume to detect the current release version of each SE network site?

Tags: support, api

Is there an API that I can consume to detect the current release version of each SE network site?

For example, during the last 5 months the design of the sites has changed, and changes have been made in a procedural way little by little, instead of validating the design of the site. I would like to be able to validate something like the version.

In my case I want to add the version detection to an extension that I have for the site, to find out if my extension is still supported or not.

I tried looking for an answer to my question among existing answers, but it seems to me that they are not related or are old ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332098/is-there-such-thing-as-a-version-of-se-that-i-can-use-only-through-my-personal-w)).

Comment: I'd say that that would be fruitless. There is a revision in the footer of each webpage (at the moment, here on Meta it is `rev 2022.4.5.41860`), but there is no semantic versioning here.

Comment: I think you may want to look at [Essential Stack Exchange user scripts and the dependencies they utilize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372957) and [Providing a JavaScript API for userscripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372956) instead.

Comment: I thought of giving support by reading this data... but what if the structure of the site changed, I wouldn't be able to read it. why would it be unsuccessful to have something like that in an api?

Comment: @MartijnPieters let me evaluate the last thing you added, thanks.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but the current API version of a site is obtainable from ... you'd guess it ... [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info).

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the information, this solves my doubt.

Comment: IIRC all SE sites except meta.SE and SO (which have dedicated servers) run on the same multi-tenant server, so you'd only need to fetch the version info for those three servers

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 might want to be careful that the API that Glorfindel mentioned is different from the site's current rev version. As of current writing MSE uses API rev 2022.3.23.848, but site rev 2022.4.5.41860.

Comment: *"I want to add the version detection to an extension [...] to find out if my extension is still supported or not."* But how would a version number help with that? Tons of updates are published that fix minor bugs or don't even change the frontend at all. The only true way to determine if your script still works is to test to see if you get expected data for what you're trying to do and, if not, display an error that something unexpected happened. A version number can't help you with that. Our release structure just doesn't make it useful information.